# Scroll event doesn't fire unless page moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-events

I'm looking to get an event to fire when one scrolls "up" from `$(window).scrollTop == 0`.

If you have the following code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    console.log("scrolling")
});
```

On a page where the document < window height then that event never fires because `$(window).scrollTop` isn't changing, but this doesn't mean that there's no mouse scroll input. I want an event to fire on mouse scroll regardless if the page is moving or not.

Comment: `$(window).scrollTop == 0` ??? jQuery's scrollTop function will never `=== 0`, unless it's been shadowed or overwritten. Did you mean `.scrollTop() === 0` ?

Comment: ...maybe when you get to `0`, have the JS set it back to `1px`. Could be it'll be a small enough change that it won't be too much of a visual distraction. http://jsfiddle.net/TKpsR/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/n8eVQ/

```
$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll', function(event, delta) {
    console.log('mousewheel');
    //you could trigger window scroll handler
    $(window).triggerHandler('scroll');
});
```

Other way is to capture `scroll` event on modern browsers which support event capturing phase (IE>8). This can be used for any dynamic element. As jQuery doesn't implement capturing phase, you have to use javascript `addEventListener()` method. Here an example implementing logic to get scrolling direction for a textarea:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    var $elm = $(event.target);
    if ($elm.is('textarea')) { // or any other filtering condition
        // do some stuff
        var direction = $elm.scrollTop() > ($elm.data('scrollTop') || 0) ? "down" : "up";
        $elm.data('scrollTop', $elm.scrollTop());
        console.log('scrolling', direction);
    }
}, true);
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: Updated answer to support FF

Comment: `delta` is undefined. How do I get direction?

Comment: You can use console.log(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta);  tested on chrome

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', callbackFunction, false);
```

Solution for firefox; for other browsers see @roasted solution